# Multiple Entries in Azure Mobile Service

Tags: mobile, azure, service

I want to push notification to Mobile devices using Azure mobile Services. My Business Layer wrapped around WCF service will invoke mobile Service REST API.

https://.azure-mobile.net/tables/

Push notification to devices will be triggered as per the code in Insert();

Rest API works fine for single record. I want to add multiple records from server side c# code

Following is the format of the JSON object
e.g.
{"TodoItem":[{"UserID":201,"complete":false,"text":"Hello"},{"UserID":202,"complete":false,"text":"Hello"}]}

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to perform multiple entries insert into the table using Azure Mobile Services.

First approach is to pass an JSON array (`entries`) to the service call and then iterate over every entry (`var toInsertEntry = entries[iterator]`) and perform `table.insert()` with every entry.

Another approach would be to convert your objects into valid SQL `INSERT` entries and use the `mssql` object to perform a batch insert operation on SQL Server.

Read [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/01/02/inserting-multiple-items-at-once-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx) for more details on the topic.

Comment: It seems like iteration would be required.. i was assuming if the Azure Mobile service accepts collection object

Comment: @HuzaifaMatawala: Yes, manual iteration is unavoidable here, unfortunately. You can't just pass a list and hope it will be inserted.